# Why do two iterators shift apart in loop?

Tags: c++, qt, iterator, qlist

I have two STL-style iterators for `QStringList` which are initialised before a loop like that.

```
QStringList::iterator it(cnamesNum->begin()),itCnam(cnames->begin()+1+totMetaData);
```

`it` points to a `QStringList` made like that

1. "1"
2. "2"
3. "3"
4. "4"
5. "5"
6. "6"

while `itCnam` points to a `QStringList` which is exactly like the previous but in this case we have an extra element at the front. So

1. "foo"
2. "1"
3. "..."

I am checking a condition for each column of a matrix and I want to delete the corresponding column names if the condition is not met.

```
for(unsigned int i=0;i<numDF.n_cols;i++,it++,itCnam++)       //Subset matrix and check RSD
    {
        vec b = numDF.submat(IdxQcs,uvec{i});
        b = b.elem(find_finite(b));

        if(b.n_elem>0)
        {
            if(stddev(b)/mean(b)<rsdPerc)    //if below retain
                keepColidx.insert_rows(ct++,uvec{i});
            else                            //otherwise keep track of removed
            {
                removed.append(*it);
                cnamesNum->erase(it);
                cnames->erase(itCnam);  // 1 is the class
            }
        }
        else
        {
            removed.append(*it);
            cnamesNum->erase(it);
            cnames->erase(itCnam);  // 1 is the class
        }
    }
```

The condition checking works as it should and the `QString` removed from `cnamesNum` and `cnames` are correct until we reach the fifth iteration where `cnamesNum` removes the correct string ("5") but `cnames` removes "6" even though they are undergoing the same treatment throughout the loop. What is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  When you call erase the iterators become invalid

> Iterators pointing to an item in a QLinkedList remain valid as long as the item exists, whereas iterators to a QList can become invalid after any insertion or removal.

([source](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html))

What you will need to do is capture the returned iterator as it will point to the next element in the list.

```
it = cnamesNum->erase(it);
itCnam = cnames->erase(itCnam);
```

You will also need to remove `it++,itCnam++` from the for loop and only incrent `it` and `itCnam` if you do not remove an element from the list.